# JQuery Dialog Box Display after disable scroll bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, messagebox

Im develop the Jquery Message box , but i can't disable scrollbar, what are the solution?

```
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
     @if (TempData["SuccessEdit"] != null)
    {
        <script>
            $(function () {
                $("#green").dialog({
                    modal: true, 
                });

            });
        </script>
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
     @if (TempData["SuccessEdit"] != null)
    {
        <script>
            $(function () {
                $("#green").dialog({
                    modal: true, 
                });

            });
$("#green").css({'overflow':'hidden'});
        </script>
    }
```

or just add a css rule to your page

```
#green {
overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: can you share the rest of your code?? you may need to use overflow:hidden !important; to overwrite css values coming from bootstrap

Comment: iam Edited Leo Javier 's solution, now its working,thanks for help everyyone :)
   <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    @if (TempData["SuccessEdit"] != null)
    {
        <script>
            $(function () {
                $("#green").dialog({
                    modal: true,
                });

            });
            $(" $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');");
        </script>
    }


       css 
body {
overflow:hidden;
}